# Running processes (mainly python) over several machines

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, job-scheduling

I would like to be able to run multiple, typically long processes, over different machines connected over a local network.
Processes would generally be python scripts.

In other words, suppose that I have 100 processes and 5 machines, and I don't want to run more than 10 processes on each machine at the same time.
My "organiser-script" would then start 10 processes per machine, then send the next ones as the first ones end.

Is there any way to do this in python?
Any suggestion would be very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you need Spark :)     http://spark.apache.org/

Comment: use Erlang =). AFAIK there is no easy way to distribute a Python threaded program over many threads.

Comment: You need some queue processes system. You could write your organizer-script in twisted https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ and "workers" in the other machines which would receive the organizer's order to start a new process and those workers also would have the information about the running processes in the "slave" machine

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your "organiser-script" you will need some program/script on each of the other machines, that listens on the network for commands from the "organiser-script", starts "workers" and reports when "workers" have finished.

But there are existing solutions for your task. Take a good look around before you start coding.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the prompt replies! What about these existing solutions? Could you mention a few?

Comment: Sorry, I have nothing at hand right now. But the task is not that uncommon.